# Vertical scrolling with mouse in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, my mouse's scroll wheel doesn't scroll a window's code. I couldn't find any settings that enable this. Does IntelliJ not support scrolling with the mouse wheel?

Comment: Voted to close as this is not about programming but general hardware/software

Comment: I've used many different IntelliJ versions on both Linux and Windows and scrolling always worked correctly for me.

Comment: Which is your IntelliJ version? Which is your operating system? Does scroll work in the other applications? Did you add any plugin? I never had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too sometimes if IntelliJ gets confused. You can try just closing and re-opening, scrolling should be enabled by default.